# How should I interpret the output of tdda.rexpy.extract?

Tags: python, regex

I am interesting in [Rexpy](https://tdda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.09/rexpy.html#the-rexpy-command) because I am looking for a tool which infers a regular expression that would match a string. Inspecting `rexpy.extract` with `help` it looked like it 'might' be what I want.

```py
extract(examples, tag=False, encoding=None, as_object=False, extra_letters=None, full_escape=False, remove_empties=False, strip=False, variableLengthFrags=False, max_patterns=None, min_diff_strings_per_pattern=1, min_strings_per_pattern=1, size=None, seed=None, dialect='portable', verbose=0)
    Extract regular expression(s) from examples and return them.
    
    Normally, examples should be unicode (i.e. ``str`` in Python3,
    and ``unicode`` in Python2). However, encoded strings can be
    passed in provided the encoding is specified.
    
    Results will always be unicode.
    
    If as_object is set, the extractor object is returned,
    with results in .results.rex; otherwise, a list of regular
    expressions, as unicode strings is returned.
```

So I tried an example:

```py
>>> from tdda import rexpy
>>> s = 'andrew.gelman@statistics.com'
>>> rexpy.extract(s)
['^[.@]$', '^[a-z]$']
```

I expected something similar to `['^[a-z].[a-z]@[a-z].[a-z]$']` rather than `['^[.@]$', '^[a-z]$']`. Is the extractor just telling me that special symbols `'.'` and `'@'` are used 'somewhere' in the string?

Comment: Based on a quick skim of the source code, `examples` should be a list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `examples` parameter expects an iterable of strings, by providing a single string as the parameter the function iterates over each individual character and is outputting regular expressions to match those single character examples.

Try providing a list of strings instead, e.g. `rexpy.extract([s])`.

Comment: Thanks! 

It gives 

`['^andrew\\.gelman@statistics\\.com$']`.

Adding more emails gives the sorts of patterns I would expect.